# Adding attributes to Savon (2.2.0) SOAP Headers

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, xml-namespaces, savon

I am working against a WSDL service that only seems to return if there is an `xmlns` attribute set in one of the authentication tags sent in the headers.  I am using Savon 2.2.0 and the following will work if I send it via a test tool:

```
 <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="XXX">
  <SessionID>XXX</SessionID>
</AuthenticationHeader>
```

But I have found no way of adding in the attribute to the tag (as it is in the header).  There's been a few older questions on SO for this, but none seemingly for v2 of Savon.

Savon currently outputs this:

```
 <AuthenticationHeader>
  <SessionID>XXX</SessionID>
</AuthenticationHeader>
```

Which unfortunately fails to authenticate.

ANY suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `soap_header` attribute in your client definitions like this:

```
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "http://....",
  soap_header: {"AuthenticationHeader xmlns=\"XXX\"" => {"SessionID"=> "XXX"}})
```

Hope it will work for you.